# I want to read a string array using bufferedreader

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, printwriter

I have a Client class that sends a string array by using PrintWriter and the Server class is then supposed to be able to receive these values but I can't find a solution in reading from a string array.

Client class:

```
    public Client(String[] data) throws IOException {
    connectToServer();
    out.println(data);
    }

public void connectToServer() throws IOException {
String serverAddress = "localhost";
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress,9898);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
}
```

Server class:
(this is the method where the Server reads whatever the Client sends)

```
public void run(){
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

//this is my problem: i can't read the value from the array using this code
while(true){
String input = in.readLine();
if(input == null) break;
}
```

Comment: `"... but I can't find a solution in reading from a string array"` -- The solution is one you will want to code yourself. Let's see your client code and your server attempt. If you show it and if you discuss your specific problems with the code, then we should be able to easily help you.

Comment: Hi phoenixWright, your question is too broad. You should first take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please include the code writing the string array, the resulting text and the code which attempts to read the text. And try to figure out the concrete problem in your reading code.

Comment: Also ... it is worth noting that there is zero benefit of wrapping an extra level of buffering around a `Reader` that will read from in-memory data.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry about that, i included my code now

Comment: Thank you for the update. Please ask if any questions about my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've a problem here:

```
public Client(String[] data) throws IOException {
    connectToServer();
    out.println(data);
}
```

This will send nonsense data, the `toString()` representation of your String array, over the socket, and if the client is sending nonsense, the server will only read in the same. Instead send your data as individual Strings using a for loop.

```
public Client(String[] data) throws IOException {
    connectToServer();
    for (String line : data) {
        out.println(line + "\n");
    }
}
```

Or I suppose that you could use an ObjectOutputStream and then just send the entire array, but either way, don't do what you're originally doing.

Comment: i didn't think of finding a way around using the Client class. Thanks!